# Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) equation using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, precipitation

I usually calculate monthly or 3-monthly Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) using spreadsheet, based on daily rainfall from weather station. Attached is the spreadsheet example [link](https://share.getcloudapp.com/GGuAXGj7).

And now I would like to use satellite precipitation estimate (raster data) to calculate the SPI. The problem is in the spreadsheet I use some function like: FREQUENCY, GAMA.DIST, NORMSINV.

Is there any similar above function in ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find ArcGIS toolbox for calculating SPI.
This toolbox was made with the same algorithm in the spreadsheet.

https://github.com/Hyun-Woo-Jo/CalculateSPI/releases/tag/v1.0

Comment: Thanks, I just downloaded the tbx file. And I have question:
- In spreadsheet example, I provide data in monthly basis, so the tbx also required monthly data in raster?
- Is it possible to calculate SPI for 6-month, 9-month or others?

Comment: I got a memory error not long after pressed Ok button. Screenshot: https://share.getcloudapp.com/X6uozlok

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think current version of the tbx need a lot of memory.
I have revised the code, and optimized the memory use a little.
If you have problem again, please let me know. 

https://github.com/Hyun-Woo-Jo/CalculateSPI/releases

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".

Comment: The new version(v 3.0) of spi calculator have solved memory error completely!

Answer (score 1):

There was a discussion at GeoNet titled [How to calculate Standard Precipitation Index (SPI) using ArcGIS](https://community.esri.com/thread/87622) which suggests that there is a way to "calculate the SPI using monthly CHIRPS CHG - Data" using the Cell Statistics tool in the Spatial Analyst toolbox.

Comment: Yes thank you, I answered that question. At that time, I found that was the simple approach to calculate the SPI using the long-term average and stdev. Then recently I found that method is not perfectly correct, we need to calculate the gamma distribution. So thats why I ask above question in here.

Comment: @user97103 You should probably have mentioned this in the question, no?